# How did you end up at the beginning of Borderlands 2 story line?

Tags: borderlands-2

I have played through Borderlands 2, but I still wonder about the beginning.

In the tutorial, you wake up on a snow covered mountain and Claptrap is trying to bring you along because he thinks you are a corpse. Claptrap pulls you up and informs you about various things.

My question is, how did Zero and the others end up on a mountain?

I heard before something about Handsome Jack but it didn't give a full explanation. Does anyone know how exactly you end up on top of a mountain?

Comment: Try...continuing the game?  Or watch the intro?

Comment: i beat the game,but i skipped the intro, i pay no attention to voices.

Comment: -1: This is in the game's opening cutscene. We expect questions to demonstrate research effort, and this is precisely the sort of question we want to avoid here on Stack Exchange. More information: [How does "proof of effort" make a question better?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179035)

Answer (score 49):

The vault hunters were on a train for the opening credits, they fight Jack's minions and rush the cab where a bomb is waiting for them, bomb goes boom and they fall into the tundra wasteland.

The opening has the [info you seek](http://youtu.be/uV3O7MWGLL0?t=4m27s).